# pyspark - why convert string(time) to timestamp return None?

Tags: pyspark

1. I have below sample pyspark dataframe, and want to extract the time from message column, and then convert the extract time to timestamp type.

> ```
> message,class
> "2022-10-28 07:46:59,705               one=1 Two=2 Three=3",classA
> "2022-10-27 10:03:59,800               four=4 Five=5 Six=6",classB
> ```

2. I tried below 2 ways, but neither of them works.

way1:

```
sparkDF.withColumn("TIMESTAMP", to_timestamp(regexp_extract(col('message'), '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)', 1),"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS"))
```

way2:

```
sparkDF.withColumn("TIMESTAMP", regexp_extract(col('message'), '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)', 1).cast("timestamp")
```

can anyone please help take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could split the `message` field by `"  "` *(multiple spaces)* and then extract the first element. the extracted element can be converted to a timestamp easily.

see example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ts', func.to_timestamp(func.split('message', '  ')[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
# |message                                                  |class |ts                     |
# +---------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
# |2022-10-28 07:46:59,705               one=1 Two=2 Three=3|classA|2022-10-28 07:46:59.705|
# |2022-10-27 10:03:59,800               four=4 Five=5 Six=6|classB|2022-10-27 10:03:59.8  |
# +---------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+

# root
#  |-- message: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- class: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: if i want to extract this "2022-11-29 07:46:59,705", how to do it?

Comment: @peace - what do the numbers after the first comma signify?

Comment: should be millionseconds

Comment: @peace - added the milliseconds as well

Comment: thanks @samkart, it works as expected. do you know why my code with regex expression return None value? the regex expression is to capture the whole time(2022-11-29 07:46:59,705) in the message column.

Comment: @peace - i suspect you might have passed the incorrect source format. see the source format i passed.

Comment: oh. thanks for the remind. i just aware of this difference.